# Which Canon 2X teleconverter model for 70-200 f2.8 L IS II USM lens?

Tags: canon, teleconverter

I recently acquired a Canon 70-200 f2.8L IS II USM lens and want to add a 2X extender. According to Canon, the newest EF 2.0X III extender is only compatible with the EF 70-200/2.8L, EF 70-200/2.8L IS, and EF 70-200/4L L zoom lenses. It seems likely that Canon WOULD include later 70-200L lenses like mine if they are also fully compatible. Or did they just neglect to update the description with later model 70-200 L lenses? Can anyone definitively confirm that the Canon EF 2.0X III is compatible with my 70-200 f2.8L IS II USM lens, and if it isn't which 2.0X model is best for my lens? Any info and/or links would be much appreciated.

Comment: "According to Canon" where, exactly? When the EF 2X III was introduced in August of 2010 it was listed as compatible with the EF 70-200mm f/2.8 L IS II USM that had been introduced a few months earlier in March, 2010.

Comment: Beyond that, most photographers are much happier with the results they get from the EF 1.4X III than the EF 2X III on any of the 70-200/2.8 lenses. The EF 2X III, while usable with a 70-200/2.8 on most EOS bodies, only reaches its potential with the lenses it was designed for: The Great White Primes like the EF 300mm f/2.8 L IS II, the EF 400mm f/2.8 L IS II, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

On the page of [EXTENDER EF1.4X III / EF2X III Instruction Manual](https://www.canon.co.uk/support/consumer_products/products/cameras/ef_lenses/others_extenders_tilt-shift_etc/extender_ef_2x_iii.html?type=manuals&language=) I see EF70-200mm f/2.8L IS II USM is compatible with the extender. Here is a snapshot:

[image]